# Powershell G-cloud attach disk to instance

Tags: powershell, gcloud

I`m following the documentation:
https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-powershell/#/google-compute-engine/GceInstance/Set-GceInstance

I cant get the following code working:

```
$disk = Get-GceDisk disk-snapshot-instance-1
Set-GceInstance -Name instance-1 -AttachDisk $disk
```

When I replace $disk for disk-snapshot-instance-1 I get the same error:

```
Set-GceInstance : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-GceInstance -Name instance-1 -AttachDisk $disk
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-GceInstance], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Google.PowerShell.ComputeEngine.SetGceInstanceCmdlet
```

The thing I don't understand is that it works for me to remove a disk when attaching it manually through the G-cloud interface.

```
Set-GceInstance -Name instance-1 -RemoveDisk $disk
```

My question:
Why can't I attach a disk to an instance with the above code, while removing the disk works?

Comment: Did you resolve this? If not, I'll try to repro it for you this afternoon. Are you using `Get-GceDisk` to set `$disk` before the remove too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct commands are:

```bsh
Set-GceInstance $instance -AddDisk $disk1 -Zone $zone
Set-GceInstance $instance -RemoveDisk $disk1 -Zone $zone
```

I create an instance with 2 disks using gcloud and then:

```bsh
Get-GceDisk | Format-List -Property Name
```

This returns:

```
Name : disk-1
Name : disk-2
Name : instance-1
```

Then I can:

```bsh
$zone = "us-west1-c"
$disk2 = Get-GceDisk disk-2
Set-GceInstance instance-1 -RemoveDisk $disk2 -Zone $zone
Set-GceInstance instance-1 -AddDisk $disk2 -Zone $zone
```

HTH